# How to invert QTableView selection with Sorting Enabled

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview, selectionmodel

The code below creates a single `QTableView` with a `QPushButton`:

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
app = QApplication([])    

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.view = QTableView(self)
        self.view.setSelectionBehavior(QTableWidget.SelectRows)
        self.view.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.view.sortByColumn(0, Qt.DescendingOrder)

        self.view.setModel(QStandardItemModel(4, 4))
        for each in [(row, col, QStandardItem('item %s_%s' % (row, col))) for row in range(4) for col in range(4)]:
            self.view.model().setItem(*each)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.view)

        btn1 = QPushButton('Invert selection')
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.invertSelection)
        self.layout().addWidget(btn1)
        self.resize(500, 250)
        self.show()

    def invertSelection(self):
        model = self.view.model()
        for i in range(model.rowCount()):
            for j in range(model.columnCount()):
                ix = model.index(i, j)
                self.view.selectionModel().select(ix, QItemSelectionModel.Toggle)


dialog = Dialog()
app.exec_()
```

....

**Step 1:**
Select the last row by clicking on any of its cells. The clicked row is highlighted blue to indicate it is now selected:

[image]

**Step 2:**
Click "Invert selection" button. The selection is properly inverted:

[image]

**Step 3:**
Now click on column header #4 to sort by last column. At this point the selection is broken (there is only one cell is selected and it is shifted wild):
[image]

Question: How to fix the issue?

Comment: I have tried it with PyQt5 5.10.1 and it works correctly, I do not observe that problem, what version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your question! ..using PyQt5 5.6.2